# First order logic: unification of Skolem constants?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, unification

My professor asks us to either prove a logical consequence by resolution or disprove it by giving a suitable interpretation.

While doing one of the tasks, I encountered a problem with skolemization. Let's say I want to prove the following consequence by resolution

$$ \exists x Q(x) \models \exists y Q(y) $$

I introduce scolem constants a, b and try to infer the empty clause from this clausal form

$$ { [Q(a)], [\neg Q(b)] } $$

I cannot unify and therefore cannot prove by resolution. According to the task, I then have to disprove through example, but I feel like this logical consequence is always true.

A second side question: if I want to show $ \forall x \exists y P(x,y) \models \exists z P(a,z) $ where a is a constant, I can disprove by choosing $ I=\langle D, \phi \rangle $ with $ D=\emptyset $, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You application of [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique) is not correct.

In order to prove that $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ you have to consider:

> all sentences in the knowledge base [the *premises* in $\Gamma$] and the negation of the sentence to be proved [the *conclusion*: $\varphi$],

i.e. the set of formulas: $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \}$.

This means that, in order to prove: $∃xQ(x) \vDash ∃yQ(y)$ you have to apply the procedure to:

> $∃xQ(x), \lnot ∃yQ(y)$,

i.e. $∃xQ(x), \forall y \lnot Q(y)$.

---

Regarding the second question, the standard semantics for FOL needs interpretations with non-empty domains.

In addition, you set of formulas has an individual constant $a$; thus, you needs domains with at least one object $a^D \in D$ to be used as interpretation for the symbol $a$.

---

---

*Added after comments*.

The problem to be answered is: $∀x∃yP(x,y),∀x(∃yP(y,x) \to Q(x)) \vDash ∃xQ(x)$.

After initial transformations, we have:

> $P(x,f(x)), \lnot P(g(w),w) \lor Q(w), \lnot Q(z)$.

Then, we have to apply [Unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) with a first substitution: $[w \leftarrow f(x), x \leftarrow g(w)]$ to the first two clauses to get: $Q(f(x))$ by Resolution.

A second substitution: $[z \leftarrow f(x)]$ applied to third clause will produce the *empty clause*.

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot to first negate the quantifier. That D needs to be non-empty, I didn't know.

Comment: I still can't solve my problem though, could you give me a tip?
I want to prove $ \{\forall x \exists y P(x,y), \forall x (\exists y P(y,x) \Rightarrow Q(x))\} \models \exists x Q(x)$. I transform to clausal form: $ \{ [P(x,g(x))], [\neg P(f(y),y)\vee Q(y)], [\neg Q(z)] \} $ and infer $ [\neg P(f(y),y)] $. So I cannot infer the empty clause. But I don't find an interpretation for which the logical consequence doesn't hold.

Comment: But wouldn't this substitution result in $ P(g(w), f(g(w))), \neg P(g(f(x)), f(x)) \vee Q(f(x)) $?

Comment: @VincentHilla - Let $E$ be an expression and let $\theta = \{ x_1 ← t_1,\ldots , x_n ← t_n \}$ be a *substitution*. An instance $E \theta$ of $E$ is obtained by **simultaneously** replacing each occurrence of  $x_i$ in $E$ by $t_i$.

Comment: I made a mistake transforming to clausal form. When resolving the implication, the exists becomes a universal quantifier.